# Angular Dynamic Controller is Optional

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am using the following method to provide a dynamic `controller` to my `directive`.

JS:

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linkFn,
    scope: {
        minWidth: '@',
        maxWidth: '@',
        itemsVisible: '@'
    },
    controller: '@',
    name: 'controllerName'
};
```

HTML:

```
<ul 
min-width="breakpoints.m"
items-visible="5"
controller-name="ProductFilteringController"
overflow-list>
```

This works just fine, however, I won't need to provide a controller in every instance of this directive. I am using it to make sure that the scopes match and I have access to scope variables and methods.

Some context; Obviously, every time the `directive` is used it creates a new `scope`, which is fine, but I am dynamically appending an `ng-click="function()"` within the directive. This means that the `function()` is now in a different scope to the controller.

I won't need to call this `ng-click` in every instance, so I won't need a `controller` for every instance.

Essentially, is there a way of saying `controller: '@' || null`?

EDIT: As a workaround I removed the isolated scope (`scope: {...}`) and I am accessing the `attrs` from the directive params, this works for what I need but doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: Have you tried `controller: '?@'`?

Comment: The part about `ng-click` in different scope than controller doesn't make a lot of sense. Perhaps a demo would help us understand this issue better.

Comment: @simeg this gives the error `Argument '?@' is not a function, got undefined`

Comment: @charlietfl I am using the controllerAs syntax for namespacing the controller, it is then in an isolated scope.

Comment: No..the isolated scope is being created by `scope:{minwidth:.....}`. Alias and isolated scope are different. Again ... create a simple demo for this.

Comment: @charlietfl my bad, got them the wrong way around. But yeah, as the `scope: {}` creates a new scope, the `ng-click` is in a parent-scope and unaccessible.

Comment: Can use `bindToController` also. There isn't enough known here to sort your issues out without you replicating problem in a demo that shows several use cases